# Integrating an arbitrary decoder into the stim framework

Tags: stim

I am currently trying to use stim to evaluate the performance of decoders other than the ones that are inbuilt into the framework (mwpm and fusion-blossom). I need to get the logical error -rate of these decoders. Suppose I implement these decoders as a python function which takes an array of syndromes as input and gives the erroneous data qubits as output, is there a way to integrate such an arbitrary function in stim? If yes, an example would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since v1.11, you can add a custom decoder by implementing a child class of [`sinter.Decoder`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.Decoder). You tell the [`sinter.collect`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.collect) method about this decoder via its `custom_decoders=` argument. (On the command line, you tell `sinter collect` about your custom decoder via `--custom_decoders_module_function`.)

Here's an example of a custom decoder. It predicts whether observables are flipped based on nonsense, so it performs terribly, but it satisfies the interface:

```
import math
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import sinter
import stim


class CustomDecoder(sinter.Decoder):
    def decode_via_files(self,
                         *,
                         num_shots: int,
                         num_dets: int,
                         num_obs: int,
                         dem_path: pathlib.Path,
                         dets_b8_in_path: pathlib.Path,
                         obs_predictions_b8_out_path: pathlib.Path,
                         tmp_dir: pathlib.Path,
                       ) -> None:
        # Read input data. Note it's not a great idea to store it in memory all at once like this.
        detector_error_model = stim.DetectorErrorModel.from_file(dem_path)
        packed_detection_event_data = np.fromfile(dets_b8_in_path, dtype=np.uint8)
        packed_detection_event_data.shape = (num_shots, math.ceil(num_dets / 8))

        # Make predictions.
        all_predictions = []
        for shot in packed_detection_event_data:
            unpacked = np.unpackbits(shot, bitorder='little')
            shot_predictions = []

            # This is a terrible way to make the prediction.
            # It doesn't even look at the error model!
            excitations = np.count_nonzero(unpacked)
            for k in range(num_obs):
                shot_predictions.append(excitations % (k + 2) == 0)

            all_predictions.append(shot_predictions)

        # Write predictions.
        np.packbits(all_predictions, axis=1, bitorder='little').tofile(obs_predictions_b8_out_path)

    def compile_decoder_for_dem(self, *, dem: stim.DetectorErrorModel) -> 'sinter.CompiledDecoder':
        # This will be added in v1.12 and sinter will prefer it, as it avoids the disk as a bottleneck.
        #
        # You have to return an object with this method:
        #    def decode_shots_bit_packed(
        #                self,
        #                *,
        #                bit_packed_detection_event_data: np.ndarray,
        #        ) -> np.ndarray:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

You can put an instance of this decoder into a dictionary and pass that dictionary to `sinter.collect` in order to use it. The name of the decoder is its key in the dictionary. For example, `custom_decoders={'MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW': CustomDecoder()}` means the decoder is called `"MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW"`:

```
tasks = [
    sinter.Task(
        circuit=stim.Circuit.generated(
            "repetition_code:memory",
            distance=d,
            rounds=d*3,
            before_round_data_depolarization=1e-2,
        ),
        json_metadata={'d': d},
    )
    for d in [3, 5, 7]
]

results = sinter.collect(
    num_workers=2,
    tasks=tasks,
    decoders=['pymatching', 'MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW'],
    custom_decoders={'MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW': CustomDecoder()},
    max_shots=10000,
)
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

```
     10000,      9475,         0,   0.070,MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW,20a39c883e35c1d6ed09bf73ed2e1690f485446078e1ab4a286a0689ce5a6331,"{""d"":3}"
     10000,        16,         0,   0.219,pymatching,0c79d325cecbb8e67646ce4f7783d673495256bad9b292d39fc1602fa5028018,"{""d"":3}"
     10000,      9100,         0,   0.039,MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW,c5d0906714ba3678300e2583bd57333205be3f110d84aa32b496f8e02daed9c1,"{""d"":5}"
     10000,         0,         0,   0.016,pymatching,1a3b24de16955403277eec3011fef54a7afde9bc9e59f9de1ef8d3763fa0b066,"{""d"":7}"
     10000,      8784,         0,   0.039,MY_AMAZING_CUSTOM_DECODER_WOW,eed26933e8a5da7e0171d7a287bbb1bfc27170dded2fdf5b0f21e1a00578c117,"{""d"":7}"
     10000,         0,         0,   0.235,pymatching,cee9d73fed658154fad401aad43fc37109e3486db697d8e8a191726195521e97,"{""d"":5}"
```

From the command line it's much more awkward to use a custom decoder, but still possible. You have to pass the argument `--custom_decoders_module_function` with an argument like `my_custom_module:CustomDecoder`. This requires your custom decoder to be in a python module `my_custom_module` (or whatever you gave to the argument) that python can import e.g. due to it being in a location in `PYTHONPATH`.